# JS - setInterval/clearInterval not working inside if-condition

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-tag-manager

I use Google Tag Manager and want to capture clicks on iframe-elements (videos). The first time a visitor clicks on the iframe, I want to push special values to the DataLayer (not included here).

This is my code so far:

```
function (){
var monitor = setInterval(isIFrame,1000);

function isIFrame(){
    var elem = document.activeElement;
    if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME'){
    clearInterval(monitor);
    alert ("x"); //The datalayer code would go here instead
   }
return;
 }
}
```

Detecting clicks on the iframes works perfectly, and the alert is working as well, but the setInterval is not being stopped by clearInterval.

I recently started coding, so any help will be appreciated.

Basically, I want the function inside the IF to run only once - and the intervall has to be used, since I have to check every second if the person has already clicked (= is active inside) the iframe. Since I use GTM, I am not able to define monitor as global variable.

Comment: have you tried `clearInterval(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the control goes into the if case. Otherwise it wont be stopped.

```
interval()
function interval(){
var monitor = setInterval(isIFrame,1000);
var elem = "document.activeElement";
function isIFrame(){
    if(elem && elem== 'IFRAME'){
    clearInterval(monitor);
    alert("x"); //The datalayer code would go here instead
   }
    elem = "IFRAME"
return;
 }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rishi0405/96nhf1x3/